# CSS problems while using Joomla

Tags: css, joomla

Firstly, I have often used this site to solve issues, however, I cannot find a solution to my CSS problem.

Background.
I am using Joomla 3.3.0 and one of the default templates, Beez20
I have added 4 further div tags which I have successfully added and styled.

Now my problem. The links in the main template pain are picking up the styling from the added divs and their styling. As I have a white back ground and I have white styling on my added divs, my active links are not showing in my main content pane.

If anyone could shed some light on what I've done wrong would be gratefully received

Comment: Sorry, should have added the Joomla tag. Thanks KunJ

Answer (score 0):

I assume the theme's styles are overwritten by your new styles. Write your new CSS styles *specifically* for your new Divs by using your own class before your new CSS classes;

e.g.
HTML:

```
<div class="my-added-divs">
<a href="...">Link</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.my-added-divs a {
/* Your styles here */
}
```

Comment: Hi Nilaksha.

I have done this. I have added a small menu bar at the top of the page and a small menu bar at the foot of the page all in their own new divs and have applied styles to them. I have used the id tag for each div and specified what I want the link to do in each state and each new div with it's menus do what I want them to do. However, in the main content (in the divs that Joomla provide) the style of my new divs has been picked up for the main content. 

Maybe when I get home, I'll copy & paste the CSS to see if it describes the problem better.

Thanks for the reply